# React re-rendering overlapping divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, infinite-scroll

I am attempting to create a sort of infinite scroll messaging component using react. I am essentially creating a div with many divs, or messages, inside it. I am mocking the data, and only loading 20 messages to start, and then attempting to load the rest of them as soon as the scrolltop of the outer div is 0, meaning the user wants to load older messages.

Here is how I fetch new messages:

```
fetchNewMessages = lastMessageId => {
    const newId = lastMessageId - 20 + 1;
    const newMessages = [
        ...this.state.selectedMessages,
        ...messages[0].messages.slice(newId < 0 ? 0 : newId, 
        lastMessageId).reverse(),
    ];
    this.setState({
      selectedMessages: newMessages,
      lastMessageId: newId < 0 ? 0 : newId,
    });
}

handleScroll = (e) => {
    if (e.target.scrollTop === 0) {
        this.fetchNewMessages(this.state.lastMessageId)
    }
}
```

The problem that I am facing is that when I load the new messages, it seems to move the divs and somehow overlap them. I researched, and other people who had similar problems said make the key unique so I gave my messages each a unique id, but this still did not fix the problem.

Here is a jsfiddle showing the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/180872/

And here is the desired output along with the actual output:
[image: Desired Output]

The above is the Desired Output

[image: Actual Output]

This is what I am getting

**Edit**: Weirdest thing that I noticed - if you highlight the messages that are overlapping/look weird, they somehow fix themselves. Additionally, if you scroll up to re-create the bad messages and then change tabs and then go back to the jsfiddle, it will show them properly. I am very confused...

Comment: Sounds like a browser rendering bug to me... try adding [`will-change: contents`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change) on the container to see if that helps.

Comment: doesn't seem to do anything :/

Comment: what browser and version are you using? I don't see any problem in Chrome 65.0.3325.181

Comment: im using the same browser and version